# Back header button in drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

How can i have a back button on some screen eg ProfileScreen/ReporterScreen such that clicking on it would take user to ContentFlow.

```
const ProfileNavigator = createStackNavigator({ ProfileScreen });
const ReporterNavigator = createStackNavigator({ ReporterScreen });

const ContentNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({ ContentScreen });

const HomeNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
 ContentFlow:ContentNavigator,
 ProfileFlow:ProfileNavigator,
 ReporterFlow:ReporterNavigator
});
```

I have added header button for drawer in ContentScreen, but for other screens i want to have back button instead, how to navigate to ContentFlow, when back button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `headerLeft` to a component in the `navigationOptions`. So for example if you want to have one or more screens inside `ReporterNavigator` that have a header button that allows a user to navigate to `ContentFlow` you could do something like this:

```
const ReporterNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Screen: {
    screen: ScreenComponent,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Button
            title="go to contentflow"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate('ContentFlow');
            }}
          />
        ),
      };
    },
  },
});
```

If you want to have the button for all screens of the `ReporterNavigator` you will want to use `defaultNavigationOptions` instead of `navigationOptions`. Keep in mind that `navigationOptions` are set inside the `RouteConfigs` and `defaultNavigationOptions` are defined in the `NavigatorConfigs` (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator/#stacknavigatorconfig).

---

When you do this:

```
const HomeNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  ContentFlow: ContentNavigator,
  ProfileFlow: ProfileNavigator,
  ReporterFlow: ReporterNavigator,
});
```

the navigation object also gets passed down. Because it gets passed down from the drawer navigator it holds its navigation state of that navigator. So you are able to navigate to screens inside the drawer navigator.

If you wanted to access the navigation state of the `ReporterNavigator` you could instead access the props in the anonymous function `headerLeft` is set to:

```
// ...
headerLeft: ({navigation}) => (
  // etc...
)
// ...
```